# Load clientid and clientsecret from the database in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication

I want to load the client id and the client secret from the database

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddGoogle( options => 
{
    options.ClientId = "";
    options.ClientSecret = "";
});
```

Comment: ...are you asking about how to implement `IClientStore` for IdentityServer? If not, then why are you using `IdentityServerConstants` here _with_ `AddGoogle()`? If you want to participate in OIDC federation you need to use a different approach: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/aspnetcore1/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html

Comment: @Dai `app.UseGoogleAuthentication` is deprecated in favour of `services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle()` as OP is doing ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.googleappbuilderextensions.usegoogleauthentication?view=aspnetcore-2.2&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-8.0)). Additionally, `IClientStore` is what provides the clients that you yourself define for your Identity Server, so I don't think that's what OP is asking, though I'm not ruling it out. 

Answer (score 0):

You can create an options configuration class and inject your database context or connection into it, something like this:

```cs
class ConfigureGoogleOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<GoogleOptions>
{
    private readonly MyDatabaseConnection _dbConn;

    public ConfigureGoogleOptions(MyDatabaseConnection dbConn)
    {
        _dbConn = dbConn;
    }

    public void Configure(string? name, GoogleOptions options)
    {
        // query the DB here and get the credentials
        options.ClientId = clientIdFromDb;
        options.ClientSecret = clientSecretFromDb;
    }

    public void Configure(GoogleOptions options)
    {
        Configure(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options);
    }
}
```

Then in addition to calling `.AddGoogle`, you also have to add the configuration class to your dependency injection container:

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<GoogleOptions>, ConfigureGoogleOptions>();
```

Note that `Configure` will be called each time the options object is resolved, so it might make sense to just load this information once (or periodically) and then cache it. Also, there isn't an `async` equivalent of `Configure` as far as I'm aware, and at least in 2018 Microsoft didn't seem keen on making one ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/2381)).

Comment: it works thank you